# Is specifying resume_offset for hybernation to LUKS-encrypted drive safe?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, luks, cryptanalysis

I need to enable hybernation to the LUKS-encrypted drive. My /boot partition is unencrypted hence it stores all kernel images as well as kernel parameters in unencrypted form. For hybernation to work I should specify where the swap file starts off on my drive where the system can write hybernated data to. For this Linux kernel has "resume_offset" parameter and the same-called /sys variable.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/power/swsusp.html

Does specifying resume_offset as a kernel command line parameter upon launching via GRUB aid cryptanalysis against my LUKS partition if my drive gets stolen? The value of resume_offset would be stored unencrypted on /boot/grub/grub.cfg. I suspect an attacker can use information about where the swapfile and the rest of my filesystem are for defeating encryption.